# How to add buffering percentage to an audio in ios

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, buffering

Hi I'm creating a radio application in ios by accessing a web service.

`

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];


    [mp prepareToPlay];
```

`

This is the way that I get the audio from the web service. Now I want to add the buffering percentage before play this audio.After it completed to 100% the audio should play. How can I do that. Pls help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

load it in background... use the performSelectorInBackgroundMethod